# make search query in adonisjs lucid

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

i have model called Apps with this tables
**id    developer_id    title   body    price   size    version category created_at updated_at**

so i want a search query by title to find the searched %string% in title

```
const apps = await Apps.query()
.where(‘title’, params.title)
.fetch()
```

the problem is this code does not search for similar string and only looks for exact mach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Lucid uses knex.js for query builder, you can use method whereRaw.
So, if you use this code may work.

```
const apps = await Apps.query().whereRaw('title like %?%', [params.title]).fetch()
```